# Find a match in line of file, then move on to next file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new in python and I'm try to write a script to loop through all the .txt files in my /home directory and iterate lines in each .txt file and see if I can find a match, if it does, it should move on to next file. If it doesn't find the match in entire file, then report it.

Code that I have:

```
strname = "ntpq -p"

for file in glob.glob("/home/xxx/*.txt"):
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        iFoundTheLine = 0
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip()
            id = line.split(b"|")[0]

            if strname in line:
                iFoundTheLine = 1
                print ("%s is ok" % id)
                break

        if iFoundTheLine == 0:
            print ("Problem with NTP%s" % id)
```

**The result that I got:**

srv29393 is ok

Problem with NTP

srv29494 is ok

Problem with NTP

srv29399 is ok

srv29493 is ok

**The expect result I'm looking for:**

srv29393 is ok

Problem with NTP srv1234

srv29494 is ok

Problem with NTP srv2345

srv29399 is ok

srv29493 is ok

**sample lines:**

srv29393|06/23/18|05:32:02|ps -eo user,pid,ppid,start,etimes,cmd | egrep -v [\w<|>nobody 22972 21597 03:06:12 8767 (dnsserver)

srv29393|06/23/18|05:32:02|1529746322|ps -eo user,pid,ppid,start,etimes,cmd | egrep -v [\w<|>nobody 22973 21597 03:06:12 8767 (dnsserver)

srv29393|06/23/18|05:32:02|ps -eo user,pid,ppid,start,etimes,cmd | egrep -v [\w<|>nobody 22974 21597 03:06:12 8767 (dnsserver)

srv29393|06/23/18|05:32:02|1529746322|/usr/sbin/ntpq -p<|>*1.1.1.11    11.11.11.11      3 u 1055 1024  377  719.042   -0.625   0.016

srv29393|06/23/18|05:32:02|1529746322|/usr/sbin/ntpq -p<|>+2.2.2.11   12.12.12.11      3 u 1049 1024  377  824.784    0.707   0.121

It is missed the "id" for those having issue for the NTP. Could someone please help/advise?

Comment: hi @hiroprotagonist, thanks for the point out. I fixed the indentation. Is there any other issue that you caught why ID is missing to report?

Comment: Put the last IF statment inside the For loop doesn't work either. :(

Comment: I got it... You have a minor issue. `iFoundTheLine = 0` should be inside `for` loop. The `if` statement was OK.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you want to accomplish and what is your 'id', but my feeling is it is something you should try to recover from outside the loop, not at every line

Comment: @MelvinAbraham, tried your suggestion but doesn't work. I got the same result

Comment: Why are you opening the text file in binary?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon, id = baxxxx as you can see the result that I provided. I could make the id to shows if I put the last IF statement inside the For loop but it will shows too many lines and false result

Comment: Please post some sample lines which is inside the text files...

Comment: @MelvinAbraham, I have some non-standard chars inside the file, even I remove it, same result.

Comment: @beeloo I'll double down on this: we need to see the text file to be able to help any further.

Comment: @beeloo Think about it... How can you get the `id` working outside the `for` loop which is calculated inside the loop itself?

Comment: @MelvinAbraham, agree, I tried to think how to achieve this.

Comment: @beeloo You should post those sample lines the question. Hard to read them as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You have a minor issue. You are trying to print `id` outside the `for` loop where the `id` is not accessible. So, it should be placed inside the loop.

Also, due to this reason, there is no reason that you should have `iFoundTheLine` variable as it is unnecessary.

**EDIT:** `for line in f` should be `for line in f.readlines()`

With some refactoring of your code:

```
import glob
strname = "ntpq -p"

for File in glob.glob("/home/xxx/*.txt"):
    with open(File, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            line = line.rstrip()
            id = line.split("<|>")[0]

            if strname in line:
                print ("%s is ok" % id)
                break

            else:
                # Since, `id` is accessible inside the loop 
                print ("Problem with NTP%s" % id)
```

Since the text file contains special characters, I recommend using `UTF-8` encoding with the file rather than accessing it in binary, as it makes the file interaction easier.

Comment: @MelvinAbraham, I tried you code and I got everything as failed :(

Problem with NTPba29393

Problem with NTPba29392

Problem with NTPba29494

Problem with NTPba29391

Problem with NTPba29399

Problem with NTPba29493

Comment: @beeloo Please post sample text file content in the question itself as it would be readable and would allow testing the code locally.

Comment: @beeloo Test the code with this change: `for line in f.readlines()` instead of `for line in f`

Comment: added sample lines

Comment: @beeloo Do the text files have multiple lines?

Comment: @MelvinAbraham, yes, and the "ntpq" lines are in the middle of over 100+ lines in each file

Comment: @beeloo With the sample data you provided, I am getting the following results when I run the above program: 
Problem with NTPba29393;
Problem with NTPba29393;
Problem with NTPba29393;
ba29393 is ok... Is that okay?

Comment: @MelvinAbraham, my expected result is if "ntpq -q" not exist in any line in file, it will reports as fail. Otherwise, it is good. 

The result that you had shows ba29393 only and some have problem and then ok, it is not the result that I'm looking for.